# Find/remove bad DNS entry in Samba

Tags: samba, dns

We added a DNS entry to Samba via the Windows DNS Manager which apparently was invalid. Now we can't see the list of forward lookup because it immediately errors and we have to restart the Samba service.

Running Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu on Ubuntu 16.04

Additionally, a samba-tool dns query fails with the following error:

```
> $ samba-tool dns query dc1.mydomain.com mydomain.com @ ALL
> ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (-1073741300, 'The transport
> connection is now disconnected.')   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 175,
> in _run
>     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/dns.py", line 994, in
> run
>     None, record_type, select_flags, None, None)
```

This samba-tool command works if I search for a specific entry instead of "@".

How do we find/delete the bad DNS entry?

Where are DNS entries stored for the internal Samba DNS?

Here is the full debug output -

```
INFO: Current debug levels:
  all: 10
  tdb: 10
  printdrivers: 10
  lanman: 10
  smb: 10
  rpc_parse: 10
  rpc_srv: 10
  rpc_cli: 10
  passdb: 10
  sam: 10
  auth: 10
  winbind: 10
  vfs: 10
  idmap: 10
  quota: 10
  acls: 10
  locking: 10
  msdfs: 10
  dmapi: 10
  registry: 10
  scavenger: 10
  dns: 10
  ldb: 10
  tevent: 10
lpcfg_load: refreshing parameters from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Processing section "[global]"
Processing section "[netlogon]"
Processing section "[sysvol]"
pm_process() returned Yes
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
Using binding ncacn_ip_tcp:dc1.acme.com[,sign]
Mapped to DCERPC endpoint 135
added interface eth0 ip=11.55.3.22 bcast=11.55.3.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface eth0 ip=11.55.3.22 bcast=11.55.3.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name dc1.acme.com<0x20>
startlmhosts: Can't open lmhosts file /etc/samba/lmhosts. Error was No such file or directory
rpc request data:
[0000] 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
rpc reply data:
[0000] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
Mapped to DCERPC endpoint 1024
added interface eth0 ip=11.55.3.22 bcast=11.55.3.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface eth0 ip=11.55.3.22 bcast=11.55.3.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name dc1.acme.com<0x20>
startlmhosts: Can't open lmhosts file /etc/samba/lmhosts. Error was No such file or directory
Starting GENSEC mechanism spnego
Starting GENSEC submechanism gssapi_krb5
Password for [acme\my-admin]:
Received smb_krb5 packet of length 275
Received smb_krb5 packet of length 1373
../librpc/rpc/dcerpc_util.c:173: auth_pad_length 0
gensec_gssapi: NO credentials were delegated
GSSAPI Connection will be cryptographically signed
../librpc/rpc/dcerpc_util.c:173: auth_pad_length 0
rpc request data:
[0000] 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 02 00 16 00 00 00   ........ ........
     t: struct dcerpc_sec_verification_trailer
        _pad                     : DATA_BLOB length=0
        magic                    : 0000000000000000
        count: struct dcerpc_sec_vt_count
            count                    : 0x0002 (2)
        commands: ARRAY(2)
            commands: struct dcerpc_sec_vt
                command                  : 0x0001 (1)
                    0x01: DCERPC_SEC_VT_COMMAND_ENUM (1)
                       0: DCERPC_SEC_VT_COMMAND_END
                       0: DCERPC_SEC_VT_MUST_PROCESS
                u                        : union dcerpc_sec_vt_union(case 0x1)
                bitmask1                 : 0x00000001 (1)
                       1: DCERPC_SEC_VT_CLIENT_SUPPORTS_HEADER_SIGNING
            commands: struct dcerpc_sec_vt
                command                  : 0x4002 (16386)
                    0x02: DCERPC_SEC_VT_COMMAND_ENUM (2)
                       1: DCERPC_SEC_VT_COMMAND_END
                       0: DCERPC_SEC_VT_MUST_PROCESS
                u                        : union dcerpc_sec_vt_union(case 0x2)
                pcontext: struct dcerpc_sec_vt_pcontext
                    abstract_syntax: struct ndr_syntax_id
                        uuid                     : 50abc2a4-574d-40b3-9d66-ee4fd5fba076
                        if_version               : 0x00000005 (5)
                    transfer_syntax: struct ndr_syntax_id
                        uuid                     : 8a885d04-1ceb-11c9-9fe8-08002b104860
                        if_version               : 0x00000002 (2)
ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (-1073741300, 'The transport connection is now disconnected.')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 175, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/dns.py", line 994, in run
    None, record_type, select_flags, None, None)
```

Comment: Can you run the samba-tool query again with a higher debug level, you can use the -d flag to set the level, I have had a similar problem, trying to remember how i solved it

Comment: Added full debug output to question above.

Comment: Ive done a brief search through the samba search, found the error is tied to "NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED" constant, it appears quite frequently when unable to connect to the socket, prehaps there is a problem with your socket ? (I think sockets are re-created when you restart samba)

Comment: I've restarted the Samba service and the entire VM many times.  Doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: at most basic, delete the last entry you made, but I would presume thats difficult to ascertain

Comment: Yes, I would like to but I don't know which one to delete.

Comment: Do you know the last entry ? Thats the one i would start with,  make sure you can still add entries before deleting one

Comment: No, I don't know the last entry.